# Read, select and rearrange columns in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a best practice question. Today i learned how to Read and write files in Pandas. How to create a Table, how to add a column and row and how to drop them.

I have an excel file with the following content:

[image]

I create a new Column "Price_average" and I average "Price_min" and "Price_max" and output it as output_1.xlsx

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlrd


df = pd.read_excel('original.xlsx')
print (df)

df['Price_average'] = (df.Price_min + df.Price_max)/2

df.to_excel('output_1.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
print (df)
```

[image]

I then prop the columns "Price_min" and "price_max" with:

```
df = df.drop(['Price_min', 'Price_max'], axis=1)
```

[image]

And lets say I want to Create This table now:

[image]

I can either delete "Age" and "Price_average" and and swap "email" with "brand" or can I simply select the Columns I want to create a new spreadsheet?

Whats the best and cleanest way to do it? To subtract the unwanted Columns from the file and rearrange and if wanted rename the columns or Pick and choose the needed columns and create a new file with them in the right order. Any suggestions? And what's the cleanest way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
selected = df[['Age', 'Price_average', 'Email', 'Brand']]
```

If you want to change column names,

```
renamed = selected.rename(columns={'Brand': 'brand', 'Email':'email'})
```

Comment: can you also post your first reply without the .rename? thanks

Comment: Can you just post the previous one underneath as a separate solution? thx man